# jquery drop down images in simple code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

- i am using **jquery-1.7.2.min.js** in my project,
- i designed like when login opened index html page,
- then client select map.html from menu then map.html loading in body,
- i given after that he got map.html file and he select area by click map,then he got pop up dialog opened with name,icon drop down and latitude,longitude.
- i getting problem is icons drop down like only image icons in drop down.
- i tried many plugins but not loading images only text getting in drop down list.
- i tried like image path as title

`<option value="0" title="..css/images/1.png"></option>`

- but not worked.
- i tried many plugins
- i tried like this also.
  `<select id="demo-htmlselect-basic">
  <option data-imagesrc="Discover-56.png" value="0"></option>
  </select>`
- please give simple plugin or any suggestions please.

Comment: You can use choosen-image: https://github.com/djgrant/chosen-image

Comment: data-imagesrc this attribute not worked in <option>. i tried choosen.js plugin,and ddlslick.js, in my project one head.html other html files loading in head.html body,so i given plugin script declation in head.html and loading map.html file but not worked.as demo all plugins worked but in application not worked.

Answer (score 3):

Try these below links for custom drop down lists.

http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick#demo

http://runnable.com/UgC2a5sY1P8LAAAj/how-to-create-a-custom-drop-down-with-images-using-jquery-ui

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/

Comment: **data-imagesrc** this attribute not worked in **<option>**. i tried choosen.js plugin,and ddlslick.js, in my project one head.html other html files loading in head.html body,so i given plugin script declation in head.html and loading map.html file but not worked.

Comment: i have also same problem.please any body give step by step implementation